# How can I fix the error I'm experiencing in my c# program?

Tags: c#, winforms, sockets, tcpclient, tcplistener

I have a single program that simulates the game "Battleships", acting as both server and client.

In the menu I choose whether to play as a server (I call the server's Start method, a console opens and I go to the game screen) or as a client (I go to the game screen).

I run the program twice, the first time selecting server and the second time selecting client.

The first interface works fine, the problem I have with the second one is that it doesn't send all the messages to the server correctly and it doesn't receive any replies.

I attach my code here:

Server.cs

```
 #region CLASE SERVER
    public class Server
    {        
        #region ATTRIBUTES
        public TcpListener tcpListener;
        public TcpClient tcpClient;
        public bool dcc = false;
        // Lista de clientes conectados
        List<TcpClient> clientes = new List<TcpClient>();

        // Instancia de ClientManager
        private ClientManager clientManager;

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        static extern bool AllocConsole();
        #endregion

        #region CONSTRUCTOR
        public Server()
        {
            clientManager = new ClientManager(clientes);
        }
        #endregion

        #region START
        public void Start()
        {
            AllocConsole(); // Agregar esta línea para crear una consola en modo Windows Forms
            try
            {
                // Crear el punto de conexión para escuchar
                IPAddress ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
                IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new(ipAddress, 8080);

                // Crear el socket TCP para escuchar
                tcpListener = new(localEndPoint);

                // Iniciar la escucha del socket
                tcpListener.Start();

                Console.WriteLine("Servidor iniciado y escuchando en el puerto 8080...");

                while (true)
                {
                    TcpClient cliente = tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();

                    // Iniciar un hilo para manejar la conexión del cliente
                    Task.Run(() => HandleClient(cliente));
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region HANDLE CLIENT
        public void HandleClient(TcpClient client)
        {
            using NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
            try
            {
                #region 1
                // Leer mensajes del servidor
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int bytesRead = stream.Read(buffer);
                string message = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                Console.WriteLine($"- Cliente {clientes.Count}: {message}");

                // Verificar si hay dos clientes conectados
                if (clientes.Count == 2)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Ambos clientes conectados.");
                    Console.WriteLine("Preprados para jugar...");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Esperando a que se conecte otro cliente...");
                }

                #endregion
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error en el cliente: {e.Message}");

                // Eliminar el cliente de la lista de clientes
                clientManager.RemoveClient(client);

                // Cerrar la conexión con el cliente
                client.Close();
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region LISTO
        public void Listo()
        {
            try
            {
                while (clientes.Count != 2)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("No hay otro cliente conectado.");
                    return;
                }
                Console.WriteLine($"El jugador {clientes.Count} está listo.");
                dcc = true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region ADD
        public void Add(TcpClient client)
        {
            clientManager.AddClient(client);
            Console.WriteLine($"Clientes conectados: {clientes.Count}");
            
        }
        #endregion

        #region REMOVE
        public void Remove(TcpClient client)
        {
            clientManager.RemoveClient(client);
            Console.WriteLine($"Clientes conectados: {clientes.Count}");
        }
        #endregion

        public List<TcpClient> GetClientes()
        {
            return clientManager.GetClientes();
        }

    }
    #endregion
```

Client.cs

```
#region CLASE CLIENTE
    public class Cliente
    {
        #region ATTRIBUTES
        public TcpClient tcpClient;
        private NetworkStream stream;
        // Instancia de ClientManager

        #endregion

        #region CONSTRUCTOR
        public Cliente() 
        {
        }
        #endregion

        #region CONECTAR
        public void Conectar(string name)
        {
            try
            {
                Server sv = new Server();
                Task.Run(() => sv.Add(tcpClient));

                // Conectar al servidor
                tcpClient = new TcpClient();
                tcpClient.Connect(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 8080);
                stream = tcpClient.GetStream();

                // Enviar datos al servidor
                string mensaje = $"Hola, soy {name}";
                byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(mensaje);
                stream.Write(buffer);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());

            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region SEND
        public void Send(string mensaje)
        {
            try
            {
                // Enviar datos al servidor 
                byte[] msg = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(mensaje);
                stream.Write(msg);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region DESCONECTAR
        public void Desconectar()
        {
            try
            {
                Server sv = new Server();
                Task.Run(() => sv.Remove(tcpClient));
                tcpClient.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
        #endregion

    }
    #endregion
```

ClientManager.cs

```
#region CLASE MANAGER
    public class ClientManager
    {
        private readonly List<TcpClient> clientes;

        public ClientManager(List<TcpClient> clientes)
        {
            this.clientes = clientes;
        }

        public void AddClient(TcpClient client)
        {
            clientes.Add(client);
            Console.WriteLine($"El cliente {GetClientes()} se ha conectado.");
        }

        public void RemoveClient(TcpClient client)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"El cliente {GetClientes()} se ha desconectado.");
            clientes.Remove(client);
        }
        public List<TcpClient> GetClientes()
        {
            return clientes;
        }

    }
    #endregion
```

Menu.cs

```
#region CLASE MENU
    public partial class MainMenu : Form
    {
        #region ATTRIBUTES
        private Server s;
        private Form1? form1;
        #endregion
        public MainMenu()
        {
            #region COMPONENTS
            InitializeComponent();
            s = new Server();
            #endregion
        }

        #region BOTÓN SERVIDOR
        private void btnServidor_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Task.Run(() => s.Start());
            form1 = new Form1();
            this.Hide(); // oculta el formulario actual
            form1.ShowDialog(); // muestra el nuevo formulario como cuadro de diálogo modal
            this.Close(); // cierra el formulario actual cuando se cierre el nuevo formulario
        }
        #endregion

        #region BOTÓN CLIENTE
        private void btnCliente_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            form1 = new Form1();
            form1.ShowDialog(); // muestra el nuevo formulario como cuadro de diálogo modal
            this.Close(); // cierra el formulario actual cuando se cierre el nuevo formulario
        }
        #endregion
    }
    #endregion
```

Form1.cs

```
#region CLASE FORM
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        #region ATRIBUTOS
        public Cliente c;
        public Server s;
        private List<Barco> barcos = new List<Barco>();
        private int barcosTotales = 3;
        private int barcosAgregados;
        #endregion
        #region CONSTRUCTOR
        public Form1()
        {
            #region INICIAL
            InitializeComponent();
            CreateButtons();
            c = new Cliente();
            s = new Server();
            btnReady.Enabled = false;
            btnAdd1.Enabled = false;
            btnAdd2.Enabled = false;
            btnAdd3.Enabled = false;
            btnClear.Enabled = false;
            btnDesconectar.Enabled = false;
            #endregion
        }
        #endregion
        #region CREAR TABLEROS
        private string GetRowLabel(int rowIndex)
        {
            const string alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
            return alphabet[rowIndex].ToString();
        }
        private void CreateButtons()
        {
            int labelWidth = 20; // ancho de las etiquetas de fila y columna
            int labelHeight = 20; // altura de las etiquetas de fila y columna
            int buttonWidth = 25; // ancho de los botones
            int buttonHeight = 25; // altura de los botones
            // Agregar etiquetas para las columnas al panel
            for (int col = 0; col < 10; col++)
            {
                Label lblCol = new Label();
                lblCol.Text = col.ToString();
                lblCol.Location = new Point((col + 1) * buttonWidth + labelWidth, 0);
                lblCol.Size = new Size(labelWidth, labelHeight);
                panel1.Controls.Add(lblCol);
                lblCol = new Label();
                lblCol.Text = col.ToString();
                lblCol.Location = new Point((col + 1) * buttonWidth + labelWidth, 0);
                lblCol.Size = new Size(labelWidth, labelHeight);
                panel2.Controls.Add(lblCol);
            }
            // Agregar etiquetas para las filas al panel
            for (int row = 0; row < 10; row++)
            {
                Label lblRow = new Label();
                lblRow.Text = GetRowLabel(row);
                lblRow.Location = new Point(0, (row + 1) * buttonHeight + labelHeight);
                lblRow.Size = new Size(labelWidth, labelHeight);
                panel1.Controls.Add(lblRow);
                lblRow = new Label();
                lblRow.Text = GetRowLabel(row);
                lblRow.Location = new Point(0, (row + 1) * buttonHeight + labelHeight);
                lblRow.Size = new Size(labelWidth, labelHeight);
                panel2.Controls.Add(lblRow);
                // Agregar botones al panel
                for (int col = 0; col < 10; col++)
                {
                    Button button = new Button();
                    button.Name = GetRowLabel(row).ToString() + col.ToString();
                    button.Text = "";
                    button.Location = new Point((col + 1) * buttonWidth + labelWidth, (row + 1) * buttonHeight + labelHeight);
                    button.Size = new Size(buttonWidth, buttonHeight);
                    button.Enabled = false;
                    button.BackColor = Color.White;
                    panel1.Controls.Add(button);

                    button = new Button();
                    button.Name = GetRowLabel(row).ToString() + col.ToString();
                    button.Text = "";
                    button.Location = new Point((col + 1) * buttonWidth + labelWidth, (row + 1) * buttonHeight + labelHeight);
                    button.Size = new Size(buttonWidth, buttonHeight);
                    button.Enabled = false;
                    button.BackColor = SystemColors.ControlDark;
                    button.Click += new EventHandler(panel2_ButtonClick); // Agrega el controlador de eventos al botón
                    panel2.Controls.Add(button);
                }
            }
        }
        #endregion
        #region READY
        private void btnReady_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            s.Listo();
            if (s.dcc)
            {
                // Habilitar los botones en el panel del oponente
                foreach (Control control in panel2.Controls)
                {
                    if (control is Button button)
                    {
                        button.Enabled = true;
                        button.BackColor = Color.White;
                    }
                }
                // Deshabilitar el botón "Limpiar"
                btnClear.Enabled = false;
            }
            else
            {
                // Si no hay dos clientes conectados, mostrar un mensaje al usuario
                MessageBox.Show("Esperando a que se conecten dos clientes.", "Mensaje",
                    MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
           
            
        }
        #endregion
        #region AÑADIR BARCOS
        #region AÑADIR PORTAAVIONES
        private void btnAdd1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CoordenadasForm form = new CoordenadasForm();
            Button button1 = (Button)sender;
            if (form.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                Point coordenadas = form.Coordenadas;
                // Comprobar que los botones correspondientes al barco elegido no estén ya ocupados por otro barco
                bool libre = true;
                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                {
                    int row = coordenadas.Y;
                    int col = coordenadas.X + i;
                    Button button = (Button)panel1.Controls.Find(GetRowLabel(row).ToString() + col.ToString(), true)[0];
                    if (button.BackColor != Color.White)
                    {
                        libre = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                // Comprobar que el barco no se extienda fuera del tablero
                if (coordenadas.X + 4 >= 10)
                {
                    libre = false;
                    MessageBox.Show("La ubicación elegida no es válida.");
                }
                if (libre)
                {
                    Barco barco = new Barco(5, coordenadas, true);
                    barcos.Add(barco);
                    barcosAgregados++;
                    // Pintar los botones correspondientes al barco en el panel1
                    for (int i = 0; i < barco.Size; i++)
                    {
                        int row = barco.Location.Y;
                        int col = barco.Location.X + i;
                        Button button = (Button)panel1.Controls.Find(GetRowLabel(row).ToString() + col.ToString(), true)[0];
                        button.BackColor = Color.DarkBlue;
                        button1.Enabled = false;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("La ubicación elegida no es válida.");
                }
            }
            if (barcosAgregados == barcosTotales)
            {
                btnReady.Enabled = true;
            }
        }
        #endregion
        #region AÑADIR YATE 
        private void btnAdd3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CoordenadasForm form = new CoordenadasForm();
            Button button1 = (Button)sender;
            if (form.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                Point coordenadas = form.Coordenadas;
                // Comprobar que los botones correspondientes al barco elegido no estén ya ocupados por otro barco
                bool libre = true;
                for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
                {
                    int row = coordenadas.Y;
                    int col = coordenadas.X + i;
                    Button button = (Button)panel1.Controls.Find(GetRowLabel(row).ToString() + col.ToString(), true)[0];
                    if (button.BackColor != Color.White)
                    {
                        libre = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                // Comprobar que el barco no se extienda fuera del tablero
                if (coordenadas.X + 3 >= 10)
                {
                    libre = false;
                    MessageBox.Show("La ubicación elegida no es válida.");
                }
                if (libre)
                {
                    Barco barco = new Barco(4, coordenadas, true);
                    barcos.Add(barco);
                    barcosAgregados++;
                    // Pintar los botones correspondientes al barco en el panel1
                    for (int i = 0; i < barco.Size; i++)
                    {
                        int row = barco.Location.Y;
                        int col = barco.Location.X + i;
                        Button button = (Button)panel1.Controls.Find(GetRowLabel(row).ToString() + col.ToString(), true)[0];
                        button.BackColor = Color.MediumPurple;
                        button1.Enabled = false;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("La ubicación elegida no es válida.");
                }
            }
            if (barcosAgregados == barcosTotales)
            {
                btnReady.Enabled = true;
            }
        }
        #endregion
        #region AÑADIR VELERO
        private void btnAdd2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CoordenadasForm form = new CoordenadasForm();
            Button button1 = (Button)sender;
            if (form.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                Point coordenadas = form.Coordenadas;
                // Comprobar que los botones correspondientes al barco elegido no estén ya ocupados por otro barco
                bool libre = true;
                for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
                {
                    int row = coordenadas.Y;
                    int col = coordenadas.X + i;
                    Button button = (Button)panel1.Controls.Find(GetRowLabel(row).ToString() + col.ToString(), true)[0];
                    if (button.BackColor != Color.White)
                    {
                        libre = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                // Comprobar que el barco no se extienda fuera del tablero
                if (coordenadas.X + 2 >= 10)
                {
                    libre = false;
                }
                if (libre)
                {
                    Barco barco = new Barco(3, coordenadas, true);
                    barcos.Add(barco);
                    barcosAgregados++;
                    // Pintar los botones correspondientes al barco en el panel1
                    for (int i = 0; i < barco.Size; i++)
                    {
                        int row = barco.Location.Y;
                        int col = barco.Location.X + i;
                        Button button = (Button)panel1.Controls.Find(GetRowLabel(row).ToString() + col.ToString(), true)[0];
                        button.BackColor = Color.LightGreen;
                        button1.Enabled = false;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("La ubicación elegida no es válida.");
                }
            }
            if (barcosAgregados == barcosTotales)
            {
                btnReady.Enabled = true;
            }
        }
        #endregion
        #endregion
        #region QUITAR BARCOS
        private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            QuitShips();
            btnAdd1.Enabled = true;
            btnAdd2.Enabled = true;
            btnAdd3.Enabled = true;
            btnReady.Enabled = false;
        }
        private void QuitShips()
        {
            foreach (Control control in panel1.Controls)
            {
                if (control is Button button)
                {
                    button.BackColor = Color.White;
                }
            }
            foreach (Control control in panel2.Controls)
            {
                if (control is Button button)
                {
                    button.Enabled = false;
                    button.BackColor = SystemColors.ControlDark;
                }
            }
        }
        #endregion
        #region ATACAR
        private void panel2_ButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button button = (Button)sender;
            foreach (Control control in panel2.Controls)
            {
                if (control is Button btn)
                {
                    btn.Enabled = false;
                }
            }
            c.Send(button.Name.ToString());
            button.Enabled = false;
        }
        #endregion
        #region CONECTAR
        private void btnConectar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (txtUser.Text != "")
            {
                c.Conectar(txtUser.Text);
                lblMisbarcos.Text = $"Barcos de {txtUser.Text}";
                btnDesconectar.Enabled = true;
                btnAdd1.Enabled = true;
                btnAdd2.Enabled = true;
                btnAdd3.Enabled = true;
                btnClear.Enabled = true;
                btnConectar.Enabled = false;
                txtUser.Enabled = false;
                lblError.Text = "";
            }
            else
            {
                lblError.Text = "Error al conectar, debe introducir un usuario.";
            }
        }
        #endregion
        #region DESCONECTAR
        private void btnDesconectar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            c.Desconectar();
            btnReady.Enabled = false;
            btnAdd1.Enabled = false;
            btnAdd2.Enabled = false;
            btnAdd3.Enabled = false;
            btnClear.Enabled = false;
            barcosAgregados = 0;
            QuitShips();
            btnDesconectar.Enabled = false;
            btnConectar.Enabled = true;
            txtUser.Enabled = true;
            txtUser.Text = "";
            lblMisbarcos.Text = "Mis Barcos";
        }
        #endregion
    }
    #endregion
```

I have tried changing the server to another programme and it has not solved anything.

Comment: If your goal is to just make two computers talk to each other I would highly recommend a higher level protocol than raw TCP. I found MQTT to be fairly easy to get started with, but there are tons of good alternatives.

Comment: Also, you are really abusing regions. There is no reason to create regions for individual methods, since any good IDE should let you collapse the method.

Comment: I have already fixed the region problem, thanks.
As for the rest, I just want the second client to be able to access all the methods without any problem, or at least understand why it can't.

Comment: Any form of network communication involves serializing and sending *messages*. You do not automatically get access to methods in another process. There are libraries that can do some of this for you automagically, but most have fallen out of favor of protocols like gRPC, http, MQTT, etc. I would forget about TCP and start with some guide like [this one](https://dev.to/eduardojuliao/basic-mqtt-with-c-1f88).

Comment: Due to the limitations of my project, I have to use TCP as the protocol. I need to find a way to make the second client work.